# Playmouth ignores the current theme

Tags: raspbian, cmdline.txt, plymouth

On startup Plymouth 0.9.2, on Raspbian Stretch, always shows the "text" theme (three square dots) regardless the current theme settings.

In fact I have:

```
$ plymouth-set-default-theme 
mark1

$ cat /etc/plymouth/plymouthd.conf 
# Administrator customizations go in this file
#[Daemon]
#Theme=text
#ShowDelay=0
[Daemon]
Theme=mark1
```

And manually launching Plymouth with:

```
$ sudo plymouthd
$ sudo plymouth --show-splash
```

leads to show the expected theme ("mark1").
Here my `/boot/cmdline.txt`:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=ee397c53-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles logo.nologo loglevel=1 fsck.mode=skip noswap ro consoleblank=0
```

I need to set anything else?

Comment: If it could be useful I've noticed the actual theme (mark1) is shown only at shutdown.